# Why is this computation of the surface area incorrect?

Tags: area, iterated-integrals

So I am asked to find the surface area of the part of the curve $$x=5y+z^2$$ that lies between the planes $y=0,y=z, z=0,$ and $z=2$.

I parametized my curve as $r(y,z)=\left<5y+z^2,y,z\right>$, found the absolute value of cross product $\left|r_{x} \times r_{y} \right|$ to be $$\left|r_{x} \times r_{y} \right|=\sqrt{4z^2-25}$$ and integrated $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{z} \sqrt{4z^2-25}\space \mathrm d y \mathrm d z$$
with a bit of help from Wolfram Alpha, and got $\frac{1}{12}(41\sqrt{41}-125)$ as an answer. Could someone please explain why this is incorrect?

Comment: a) You should be considering $r_y \times r_z$, which I think you are and b) notice that $4z^2 - 25 < 0$ on your entire domain. So something has gone very wrong in the computation leading up to the area form.

Comment: Also, when you say that you get some number out of WolframAlpha, how? I punched your integral in and got $49i/6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your computation.

- First, you write $r_x \times r_y$ when computing the differential area. I think you mean $r_y \times r_z$, based on your parameterization.
- Your computation of the magnitude of the cross product doesn't make sense: $4z^2 - 25$ is strictly negative on your region, and so its square root is complex.
- Your computation of the integral is apparently incorrect as well. WolframAlpha shows that 
  $$\int_0^2 \int_0^z \sqrt{4z^2 - 25} \, dy \, dz = \frac{49i}{6}$$
  which is a complex number because of the complex integrand.

---

For a starting point in a better direction, notice that

$$r_y \times r_z = \langle 5, 1, 0 \rangle \times \langle 2z, 0, 1\rangle = \langle1, -5, -2z\rangle$$

so that $|r_y \times r_z| = \sqrt{4z^2 + 26}.$

Comment: I see the problem now, and it is indeed as you pointed out